# Check array is empty in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form using Laravel with two inputs text:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('price', 'Preço') !!}
        <div class="input-group multi-control-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">De</span>
            {!! Form::text('price[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            <span class="input-group-addon">Até</span>
            {!! Form::text('price[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my function for validation:

```
if(!empty($request->year)) { 
   dd($request->year);
}
```

But when submit form without set values the array empty pass in validation and show two positions no values.

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => ""
  1 => ""
]
```

I want make this array fails in validation. How to do this validation ?

Comment: You could check for `empty` on all elements, and only return true if at least one of them is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text inputs are submitted even if empty.  Since you put these in an array they are empty elements, but still elements preventing the array from being empty.  Filter out empty elements and then check:

```
if(!empty(array_filter($request->year))) {
    dd($request->year);
}
```

Do note that the string `0` will be filtered out as well.  If that is a problem then you'll need an alternate method such as looping through the array and checking for `""`.